# Where can I find an up to date list of Browsers (and Versions) Supported by Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, grid, selenium-webdriver

I would like to maximize the stability of my grid by using the most supported Web Browser versions. I can find a list of browsers on the [SeleniumHQ](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp#supported-browsers-and-platforms) website ...however this appears to be quite out of date, mentioning Firefox 7 for example.

Am I missing something?

Really Appreciate your advice,
Kind Regards,
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That list, whilst out of date, is generally right.

You probably won't find an updated list (since the website isn't updated all that often), however I have just scraped this information from one of the Selenium mailing lists:

1. Firefox: earliest ESR release and upwards, **currently** that is Firefox 10 and upwards.
2. IE: 6 and upwards.
3. Chrome: 12 and upwards

It must also be said the following two points:

Don't be too surprised if, as you go down in version numbers (older versions of the browser), you may end up hitting weird issues.

As Firefox has a quick release schedule, you can end up with the latest version of Firefox being completely incompatible with Selenium. This can be offset by disabling Firefox's auto-updates altogether (you could argue, that user's may not be updating straight away so your UI tests may not *necessarily* need to be run against the latest version).

Comment: Thanks Arran, good, clear answer. Aligns with my findings too: when trying much older versions I got the odd exception about certain features not being supported and the Chrome WebDriver flat-out refused to work without an update :)